# how can I make a <a> tag so that when I click that <a> tag,the URL should not go in the address bar?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jquery, struts

In My JSP ,I have an `<a href="patient/tools.do?Id=<%=mp.get("FROM_RANGE") %>">
<%= mp.get("DESCRITPION") %></a>` ....when i click the anchor tag the url normally goes in the Address bar.I want the URL not to go in the Address bar.how can i do that?

Please note that `<%=mp.get("FROM_RANGE") %>` and `<%= mp.get("DESCRITPION") %>` are all scriptlets for getting value from java variables...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. (Why do you need to do it anyway?)

But you could open the link via AJAX - but then you'd need to process the returned data via JavaScript.
Or you could use frames. They are horrible and annoying for users though.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate .htaccess and URL rewrites. I do not believe you can change the not change the url in an `<a>` tag. An example also of using javascript to change the url is in a game(mentioned on slashdot) that is played entirely in the url bar. http://probablyinteractive.com/url-hunter . Check out the source code and mabye you could derive something from that.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use IFrame and change URL for that iframe. Make iframe as big as the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to do this:

1. Wrap your contents in a frameset or iFrame.
2. Load your contents dynamically using AJAX.
3. If you have a control over the domain name, then you can use [domain masking technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_masking)